# two different ng-app within same application and use the $router for routing between both the modules?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can i have two different ng-app within same application and use the $router for routing between both the modules?As i understand one cannot use two ng-view within same app

High level concept:

Load Index.html
{

```
     <ng-view>: Load Login.html Here.
             On Successfull Login, Load Home.html here
                                       {
                                         <ng-view>: Load HomePartials.html & other partials
                                         on redirect go back to ng-view of index.html where Login.html would be loaded
                                          </ng-view>
                                       }
 </ng-view>
```

}

Please share your thoughts on this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than 1 ng-app directive per html document:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp

You can manually bootstrap several angular modules, but you will not be able to use routes for more than one of them since they use the window location